# How can I execute a .bat recursive for loop over all files when some paths have spaces?

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, filenames

I am trying to write a .bat file that will do a for loop recursively over all jpg files, when some of the files have spaces in the path. This is my current attempt:

```
for /R %%F in (*.jpg) do convert %%F -colorspace rgb...
```

The problem is, the program (ImageMagick) can't take files whose paths have spaces (without quotes), so throws an exception in these circumstances. I've read loads of stackoverflow articles on dealing with spaces in bat files, but none have answered the question of how to deal with spaces when looping through all file types using an asterisk.

Comment: As you say, the problem is the lack of quotes: `for /R %%F in (*.jpg) do convert "%%F" -colorspace rgb...`

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it!